# I want to create lines according to the number of inputs of datatable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, datatable

I want to create lines according to the number of inputs in the rows of datatable,desired result: 2 * 2 = 4 but the result I get is 2 * 4 = 8. please i need help , thank you in advance.

```
    HTML:

        @foreach($detail_planning as $details)
             <tr id='lignesPlanningType'>
                <td hidden></td>
                <td class='text-center text_vertical td_profil_total'>{{$details->libelle}} EX<input type='hidden' name='hidden_profil_total[]' class='hidden_profil_total' value='{{$details->total}}'><input type='hidden' name='hidden_id_profil[]'  value='{{$details->id_profil}}'></td>

                <td class='text-center text_vertical'><div class='row'><div class='col-md-6'><div class='input-group'><input type='text' onchange='calculer_somme_heure_lundi()' class='form-control timepicker timepicker-24 input_heure_de input_heure_lundi_de'  name='input_heure_lundi_de[]'  placeholder='hh:mm' value='{{$details->new_lundi_heure_de}}' title='Lundi de' readonly /><span class='input-group-btn'> <button class='btn default' type='button'><i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i></button></span></div></div><div class='col-md-6'><div class='input-group'><input type='text' onchange='calculer_somme_heure_lundi()' class='form-control timepicker timepicker-24 input_heure_a input_heure_lundi_a' name='input_heure_lundi_a[]'  placeholder='hh:mm' value='{{$details->new_lundi_heure_a}}' title='Lundi a' readonly/><span class='input-group-btn'><button class='btn default' type='button'><i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i></button></span></div></div></div><input type='text' name='input_total_lundi[]' class='input_total_lundi input_total' value='' hidden>
                <button type='button' class='btn blue-madison btn_ads btn_ads_lundi'>Affecter</button>
                <input type='hidden' name='hidden_id_agent_lundi[]' class='hidden_global_id_agent_1 hidden_id_agent hidden_id_agent_lundi hidden_id_agent_lundi_1' />
                <input type='hidden' name='hidden_id_agent_lundi[]' class='hidden_global_id_agent_2 hidden_id_agent hidden_id_agent_lundi hidden_id_agent_lundi_2' />

                </td>
              </tr>
        @endforeach

    My code laravel :
        $input = Request::only('hidden_id_profil','table_input_profil','input_heure_lundi_de','input_heure_lundi_a');
        for ($i=0; $i < count($input['hidden_id_profil']); ++$i) 
        {       
            for ($j=0; $j < count($input['hidden_id_agent_lundi'] ); ++$j) 
            {                       
                $new_details_planning_programme = new PlanningAdsAffecte();
                $new_details_planning_programme->id_planning_prestation = $id_planning_prestation;
                $new_details_planning_programme->id_profil = $input['hidden_id_profil'][$i];
                $new_details_planning_programme->lundi_heure_de = date('Y-m-d '.$input['hidden_hr_lundi_de_agent'][$j].':s');
                $new_details_planning_programme->save();
            }
        }
```